# Let $f:[0,1]→\mathbb{R} $with $f′(x) $continuous. It is known that $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, indefinite-integrals

Let $f:[0,1]→\mathbb{R}$ with $f'(x)$ continuous. It is known that $∫_0^1 f(x) dx=0$.

Prove that $∀α∈[0,1]$, 
$$|\int_{0}^{\alpha} f(x) dx |≤ \frac{1}{8}   sup_{(0≤x≤1)}|f'(x) |$$

My answer so far :

For $\alpha = 1$ then of course the inequality applies, since it is known that $∫_0^1 f(x) dx=0$.

$$$$
Now for $\alpha \ne 1$,

Since $f:[0,1]→\mathbb{R}$ and $f'(x)$ continuous, then $f'(x)$ has extreme value for some $c \in [0,1]$ such that $|f'(c)| = sup_{(0≤x≤1)}|f'(x) |$. Let $M = |f'(c)|$.

Now since $∫_0^1 f(x) dx=0$, then there exist $k \in [0,1]$ such that $f(k)=0$.

Notice that for $x\ge k$, $f(x) = \int_{k}^{x} f'(t) dt \le (x-k) | M |$ so that $| \int_{0}^{\alpha} f(x) dx | \le(\frac{\alpha^2}{2} - \alpha k)|M| $,

Then i dont know what else to do...

Another way :

I have an idea to define a function $g(t) = \int_{0}^{t} f(x) dx$ then $g(1) = g(0) = 0$.

Any suggestion or hint for this problem??

Comment: $(x-k)|M|$ should be $|x-k|M$, shouldn't it? This makes your later claims false. But the general idea looks promising.

Comment: thanks @TonyK i have edited the post, it is for $x \ge k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Continuity of $f'$ is useless**. Following your notation, let
$$M:=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f'(x)|.$$
If $M=\infty$, there is nothing to prove, so let us suppose $M<\infty$. Following your thoughts, let 
$$g(t)=\int_0^t f(x)dx=-\int_t^1f(x)dx,\quad t\in[0,1].$$
By continuity, there exists $t_0\in [0,1]$, such that

$$|g(t_0)|=\max_{t\in[0,1]}|g(t)|,$$
and it suffices to show that 
$$|g(t_0)|\le \frac{M}{8}.$$
If $g(t_0)=0$, there is nothing to prove, so let us suppose $g(t_0)\ne 0$. Then $t_0\in(0,1)$ and $g$ attains either its maximum value or its minimum value at $t_0$, so $$f(t_0)=g'(t_0)=0. $$
If $t_0\le \frac{1}{2}$,
$$|f(x)|\le M(t_0-x),\ \forall x\le t_0\Longrightarrow |g(t_0)|\le M\int_0^{t_0}(t_0-x)dx=\frac{M}{2}t_0^2\le  \frac{M}{8}.$$
If $t_0\ge \frac{1}{2}$,
$$|f(x)|\le M(x-t_0),\ \forall x\ge t_0\Longrightarrow |g(t_0)|\le M\int_{t_0}^1(x-t_0)dx=\frac{M}{2}(1-t_0)^2\le  \frac{M}{8}.$$

Comment: A continuous function on a compact interval always attains its extremes. So $M$ can't be $\infty$.

Comment: @TonyK: Please see the first sentence in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try to digest your answer for a moment. But the continuity of $f'(x)$  is needed to guarantee that $sup |f'(x)|$ exist

Comment: I think that's right $-$ if $f$ is continuous and differentiable, but $f'$ is not continuous, then $|f'|$ must be unbounded.

Comment: @anbarief: $M=\sup|f'(x)|$ always exists, but it could be infinity. Continuity guarantees that $M$ is finite. However, if $M=\infty$, there is nothing to prove.

Comment: That's true enough!

Comment: @TonyK: Consider this classical example: $f(x)=x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}$ for $x\ne 0$ and $f(0)=0$. $f'$ exists everywhere and is bounded on $[-1,1]$, but it is discontinuous at $0$.

Comment: Yes, you're right.